# Import test case steps using c# into TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a very large excel spreadsheet that so far I can get most of the data into TFS test cases properly EXCEPT the steps.  I want the steps to show up as they do if I were inputting them manually i.e. separate steps on the form.  I'm using C#/VS2013/TFS2013.2.  How do I put in a step and associate it with the test case?

Comment: Hi Adrian. Welcome. Can you perhaps add some screenshots to help people answer your question? If you could flesh out exactly what the desired result is as well, that would probably be helpful, and maximise the chances of you getting a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is here:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/10/07/tfs-api-part-51-adding-test-step-amp-shared-step/

This blog post details the process perfectly.

Comment: The Shai Raiten's Blog is great when programming against the TFS API